# Are gentiles obligated to fear Hashem (or at least fear punishment)?

Tags: gentiles, sin, reward-punishment, noachide-laws, yirat-shamaim

As Jews we are commanded to fear Hashem and fear punishment to help us avoid sinning. 
See [Chinuch 432](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaChinukh.432.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) for example:

> ונוהגת מצוה זו בכל מקום ובכל זמן ובכל מין האדם, וזאת אחת מן המצות התמידיות על האדם, שלא יפסק חיובן מעל האדם לעולם, אפילו רגע אחד, ומי שבא דבר עברה לידו חיב להעיר רוחו ולתת אל לבו באותו הפרק, שהשם ברוך הוא משגיח בכל מעשה בני אדם, וישיב להם נקם כפי רע המעשה. והעובר על זה ולא שת לבו בכך באותן שעות בטל עשה זה, שזו היא שעת קיום עשה זה בכוון. ואולם כל ימי האדם וכל עתותיו בכלל המצוה לעמד זריז ונזכר עליה.
>
> And this commandment is practiced in every place and at all times and by the entire human species. And this is one of the constant commandments upon a person, that the obligation not ever be interrupted from upon a person, even one instant. And one upon whom the matter of a sin comes to his hand is obligated to arouse his spirit and to place into his heart at that juncture that God, blessed be He, oversees all of the actions of people and [takes] vengeance according to the evil of the deed. And one who transgresses this and does not [appraise] his heart of this at those times has violated this positive commandment; as this is the specific time [for the] fulfillment of this positive commandment. However for a person to stand with alacrity and to remember it during all of his times is included in the commandment [as well].

I know its not part of the [Sheva Mitzvos Benei Noach](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.56a.24?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) but do gentiles also have some sort of concept of fearing God or fearing punishment? Thanks.

Comment: You quoted him as saying "and by the entire human species" so I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: Interesting. I hadn't read their translation. I just included it because the good folks of Mi Yodea like it. That's not the way I understood ובכל מין האדם but it's likely that they're correct.

Comment: You could edit the source out of your question and put it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Chinuch quoted in the question clearly states that this mitzvah applies to all of the human species, ובכל מין האדם. R. Yonasan Steif (Mitzvos Hashem, p. 381) writes as well that it seems that Bnei Noach are obligated in this mitzvah (and the footnotes cite the Chinuch).

Comment: Can you provide a link or a scan to the Mitzvos Hashem? I can't find the one by Rav Steif on Hebrew books or Otzar Hachochmah?

Comment: Hebrewbooks and Otzar Hachochmah have the first edition, which doesn't include the section on mitzvos bnei noah